# How can I fix the error How To Fix Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an error coming from my user reducer code. This is what i have done.

```
export const userReducer = (
  state = localStorage.getItem('user') !== undefined
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    : null,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN_USER':
      return action.payload
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I don't know if i'm declaring the state very well. I feel thats where the issue is coming from.

I hve tried to declare my state as

```
export const userReducer = (
  state = localStorage.getItem('user') 
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) 
  : null, 
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN_USER':
      return action.payload
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I still get same error and my page does't load. It renders a blank screen, with the error in the console.

Comment: You could always try `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || 'null')` - but in all likelihood, the data in your localStorage isn't valid JSON. I mean, most likely this error is happening because what you got back wasn't JSON, and you stored in in your localStorage.. Usually because that file isn't found and the server returns an HTML page explaining the 404 status of that file, and you wrote it away without checking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "safe" JSON parser, that handles a lot of funky/broken/bad/corrupt JSON:

```
function jparse(str) { 
    var result = null; 
    try { 
        result = JSON.parse(str) 
    } catch (e) {
        // ignore
    } 
    if (!result) {
        try {
            result = Function('return (' + str + ")")();
        } catch(e){
            // ignore
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log( jparse(null) );            // null
console.log( jparse('{bob:"er"}') );    // {bob: 'er'}
console.log( jparse('{\'bob\':"er"}') );// {bob: 'er'}
console.log( jparse('{bob:}') );        // null
console.log( jparse(0) );               // 0
console.log( jparse(false) );           // false
console.log( jparse(undefined) );       // undefined
```